# Getting Annotation processor 'com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.RfValidator' not found error while try to setup GWT project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, gxt

Getting "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.apt.rfvalidator' not found 
" error when trying to setup existing project in Intellij Idea

Include all web.bindery.apt, client and server libraries in classpath but still not able to resolve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am also getting same error. please help anybody to solve this issue.

Comment: which version you are using for GWT

Comment: Have you enabled annotation processor in IDEA?

Comment: @HituBansal I am using GWT-2.8.2

Comment: @don yes i have also tried by enabling annotation processing but still getiing same error

Answer (score 0):

From the **IntelliJ IDEA** menu select *Preferences* > *Build, Execution, Deployment* > *Compiler* > *Annotation Processors*. Select the *Processor path:* radio button and set the path to the full path to requestfactory-apt.jar. For me that path is */Users/myusername/dev/gwt-2.8.0/requestfactory-apt.ja*r